# Message Notification from main frame to the Dockpane dialog

Tags: c++, mfc

I am using the SDI MFC application. I created a dockpane dialog in the mainframe. I have my view class derived from **CListView**. Whenever user clicks on the Listview in the mainframe I want to show the selected row data in the dialog. Can anybody tell me how I can achieve this and also how I can post messages from the mainframe to the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the method to update the data in control bar window to update details for selected item directly from selection change handler in your view like this:

```
void CMyListView::OnItemChanged(NMHDR* pNMHDR, LRESULT* pResult) 
{ 
    NM_LISTVIEW* pNMListView = (NM_LISTVIEW*)pNMHDR; 

    // Did the item state change?
    if (pNMListView->uChanged & LVIF_STATE)
    {
        // Did the item selection change?
        const bool oldSelState = (pNMListView->uOldState & LVIS_SELECTED) != 0x0;
        const bool newSelState = (pNMListView->uNewState & LVIS_SELECTED) != 0x0;
        const bool selStateChanged = oldSelState != newSelState;
        if(selStateChanged)
        {
            // selection has changed
            CMainFrame* pMainWnd = (CMainFrame*)AfxGetMainWnd();
            CItemDetailsWnd* pDetailsWnd = pMainWnd->GetDetailsDialogBar();
            CItemData* pItemData = (CItemData*)GetListCtrl().GetItemData(pNMListView->iItem);            
            pDetailsWnd->PopulateDetails(pItemData);
        }
    }
    *pResult = 0; 
}
```

In this example `CItemData` is your data holder for single `CListView` item/row.
The `CItemDetailsWnd` is your dialog control bar used to show details for currently selected item.

Comment: CItemDetailsWnd - what is this.....pointer to the dockpane class or dialog class

Comment: In this example it is just a pointer to dockable pane.